# Is displaying an image using matplotlib.pyplot a graph?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Input:

```
import scipy.misc
import matplotlib.pyplot
matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(scipy.misc.lena())
```

The following code displays an image of a woman on a 500 x 500 grid. 
My questions are as follows:

 1.Is this technically considered a graph? (From my knowledge a graph is the relationship between an x coordinate to a y coordinate, this seems to not be the case, but the numbers on the sides makes it confusing)

2.What do the numbers on the x and y axis represent? Is that only the sizing?

Comment: 2) Yes, these are the coordinates of each of the pixels; or the sizing overall.  1) More interpretive.. overall it's just a plot of the data in the file; but the term "graph" has different meanings in different fields so if you want to get super technical, that's hard to answer directly; but if you feel like a graph and a plot are the same thing then, yes, it's a graph.  Overall though, many different types of data can be represented by such an image -- here it just happens to be a picture of a person.

Comment: You can use the `extent` kwarg to resize the image to an arbitrary size in data-units.